# optimize variable with dynamic shape

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use a variable where the shape is unknown in advance and it will change from time to time (although ndim is known and fixed).

I declare it like:

```
initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer()
shape = (s0, s1, s2)  # these are symbolic vars
foo_var = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=shape), name="foo", validate_shape=False)
```

This seems to work when I create the computation graph up to the point where I want to optimize w.r.t. this variable, i.e.:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1, epsilon=1e-4)
optim = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[foo_var])
```

That fails in the optimizer in some function `create_zeros_slot` where it seems to depend on the static shape information (it uses `primary.get_shape().as_list()`). (I reported this upstream [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5972).)

So, using the optimizer works only with variables with static shape?

I.e. for every change of the shape of the variable, I need to rebuild the computation graph?
Or is there any way to avoid the recreation?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing does not make any sense.  How would you optimize the values of a dynamic variable if its shape is changing?  Sometimes a value would be there and sometimes it would not.  When you go to save the graph which shape would the variable be in?  The adam optimizer also needs to store information about each parameter in a variable between executions which it can not do without knowing the size.

Now if what you are looking to do is only use part of the variable at a time you can take slices of it and use them. This will work fine so long as the variable has a fixed shape of the maximum bounds of the slice.  For instance...

```
initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer()
shape = (S0, S1, S2)  # these are now constants for the max bounds of si
foo_var = tf.Variable(initializer(shape=shape), name="foo")

foo_var_sub = foo_var[:s0, :s1, :s2]
```

In this case the optimizer will only act on the parts of foo_var which contributed to the slice.

Comment: During optimization, it wont change. At some point, I reset it explicitly to a new value which will likely have another shape. Then I want to do optimization again. I don't want to recreate the computation graph every time.

Comment: If optimization does not affect it try setting the variable as not trainable when created.

Comment: But I want to optimize especially this variable.

Answer (score 0):

My solution at the moment is a bit ugly but works.

```
def _tf_create_slot_var(primary, val, scope):
  """Helper function for creating a slot variable."""

  from tensorflow.python.ops import variables
  slot = variables.Variable(val, name=scope, trainable=False, validate_shape=primary.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  if isinstance(primary, variables.Variable) and primary._save_slice_info:
    # Primary is a partitioned variable, so we need to also indicate that
    # the slot is a partitioned variable.  Slots have the same partitioning
    # as their primaries.
    real_slot_name = scope[len(primary.op.name + "/"):-1]
    slice_info = primary._save_slice_info
    slot._set_save_slice_info(variables.Variable.SaveSliceInfo(
        slice_info.full_name + "/" + real_slot_name,
        slice_info.full_shape[:],
        slice_info.var_offset[:],
        slice_info.var_shape[:]))
  # pylint: enable=protected-access
  return slot


def _tf_create_zeros_slot(primary, name, dtype=None, colocate_with_primary=True):
  """Create a slot initialized to 0 with same shape as the primary object.

  Args:
    primary: The primary `Variable` or `Tensor`.
    name: Name to use for the slot variable.
    dtype: Type of the slot variable.  Defaults to the type of `primary`.
    colocate_with_primary: Boolean.  If True the slot is located
      on the same device as `primary`.

  Returns:
    A `Variable` object.
  """
  if dtype is None:
    dtype = primary.dtype
  from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
  val = array_ops.zeros(
      primary.get_shape().as_list() if primary.get_shape().is_fully_defined() else tf.shape(primary),
      dtype=dtype)
  from tensorflow.python.training import slot_creator
  return slot_creator.create_slot(primary, val, name, colocate_with_primary=colocate_with_primary)


def monkey_patch_tf_slot_creator():
    """
    The TensorFlow optimizers cannot handle variables with unknown shape.
    We hack this.
    """
    from tensorflow.python.training import slot_creator
    slot_creator._create_slot_var = _tf_create_slot_var
    slot_creator.create_zeros_slot = _tf_create_zeros_slot
```

Then I need to call `monkey_patch_tf_slot_creator()` at some point.